# AJV does not throw type errors when given incorrect schema for a Union type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I have a pretty large interface, `FooBase`, as well as some other interfaces `FooOne` and `FooTwo` that extend `FooBase` but have a few fields set to specific constant values and have a few additional fields.

```
enum EnumField {
  ONE = 'ONE',
  TWO = 'TWO'
}

interface FooBase {
  bar: string;
  baz: string;
  // many other fields
}

interface FooOne extends FooBase {
  enumField: EnumField.ONE
  extraField: string
}

interface FooTwo extends FooBase {
  enumField: EnumField.TWO
}

type Foo = FooOne | FooTwo;
```

I want to use ajv and JSONSchema to construct a validator for `Foo`. I want ajv to tell me when my schema does not match the type. For a straightforward non-union interface, ajv will tell me if I have properties missing or have an incomplete or incorrect type. However, with the union, it seems like ajv is getting tripped up:

```
const FooSchema: ajv.JSONSchemaType<Foo> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    bar: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    baz: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    enumField: {
      type: 'string'  // underspecified, can't be any string
    }
  },
  required: []
}
```

I would expect the above to fail because the `enumField` is underspecified and there is no mentioned made of the `extraField` on `FooOne`. However, it compiles without issue. In fact, I can make this worse by giving the wrong type for `extraField`, and it will still compile:

```
const FooSchemaThatsDefinitelyWrong: ajv.JSONSchemaType<Foo> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    bar: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    baz: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    enumField: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    extraField: {
      type: 'number'  // should be string, if anything
    }
  },
  required: []
}
```

All of this can also be found in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.7.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM4oFYDc4DMoQhwDky2xA3AFBUCmAdgK5ECiTIAYsLQDYAmcAN5U4cAPIA5FnAC8JSS2IAaEXAAqAdTGySmscSoBfGsHoxaUXMgDGtOBwgQAQmjvDRAI2RQAXHFQwUKYA5tSeyABefgFB9KGqAPQJcCDI9ACecBAwABYWeNz8qEYmZhZWtvaOYvR2tAAe5vR86A7OrkKqDMxcvHx+bD2FfAB0Cl2NUMi9-NGBISVUpuaWNnZtagDuEHANTS1V7ahuXewz-XCDnMMjeosw6WDrjjptNXYAPodbENRU1hB6AFDgBlax5VJ+MhYEYAKRBkjBEOQaketAAPG0AHw6dxwB5PPzECAeDC0awwZSqMAEJ6wbioPx48K+Tqidn4tFEmIhAwcwwqDleKJsjmcwkkHlxPnsgWqUTda59Jny9kE2jc+bS1XGURy0RQWgAR0YwENFwA2gBdRYAoHwNpI2ipNQ5ZAwVAAEVouFMwHMPHSGgIcSh2DhCIkTpdaMxjhxcjx6qJJLJFKpohpEDpMAZKqF3nzYuTkq1wRlesF7OFRY5JeIUvLOqrCrOw1raq5pdiTf5Ld2k2m7dFda7xHYHgsFbgupnVcNJrNtEtNuM-0BqAgPFoIx4EGCAApHeDncgAJTroFbnd7w-H5Gu91en1+gNBkPBM9AA).

I would have expected ajv to tell me to use a oneOf to resolve this, but instead it just ignores any issues. What's going on here? Is this just a fundamental limitation of ajv?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an ajv limitation.
It says in [the documentation](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html) that "utility types JSONSchemaType [...] to convert data type into the schema type to simplify writing schemas, [...] for JSON Schema (but without union support)."